Transform and revolute the bounding object in Webots
enter image description here
The above picture shows the visualization link and collision volume of upper_arm_link in rviz. But when I use urdf2webots, the position of the collision volume in webots changes.
enter image description here
You can see that in webots, the collision volume deviates from my ideal position. It seems that the origin tag in urdf does not work.
I would like to know one of the following two points:

How to write urdf so that the correct collision volume can be obtained after using urdf2webots
Is there a way to adjust the translation and rotation of the bounding object in webots?

I'm sure everything looks correct in rviz, but after using urdf2webots an error occurs.

Please share this issues to the urdf2webots repo together with the URDF so we can reproduce the issue
